# A property of viewcontroller disappears after viewDidLoad has been called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am writing an app for iphone (iOS 7, Xcode5), and found some strange behaviour from one of the viewController classes (TrackDetailsViewController):

When this view is getting called i pass a Track item with some information i deed through the prepareForSegue method. Now When i check for the Track Item in the viewDidLoad method it exists and has all the data i expect it to have. However, when I check it again in the viewDidAppear the Track Item has become zero (see code below):

TrackDetailsViewController.h:

```
@interface TrackDetailsViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) Track *track;

@end
```

TrackDetailsViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //check for track
    if (_track !=nil) {
        NSLog(@"track not nil");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"no track");
    }

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated{

    //check for track
    if (track != nil) {
        NSLog(@"track not nil");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"no track");
    }
}
```

Now the log after running this code (after showing the view in question) looks like:

```
2013-09-28 16:25:31.877 I-Sail[1388:c07] track not nil
2013-09-28 16:25:32.235 I-Sail[1388:c07] no track
```

So, somewhere in-between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear, the value of the track property was changed to null.

After that the whole thing becomes even weirder to me, since the track property keeps its value when i add a variable track2 to the .m file, and assign the value of the track property to the track2 variable like shown in the code below:

```
Track *track2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //check for track
    if (_track !=nil) {
        NSLog(@"track not nil");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"no track");
    }

    //assign the value of _track to the track2 variable
    track2 = _track;

}

-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated{

    //check for track
    if (_track !=nil) {
        NSLog(@"track not nil");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"no track");
    }
}
```

This time the output becomes:

```
2013-09-28 16:35:57.929 I-Sail[1452:c07] track not nil
2013-09-28 16:35:58.286 I-Sail[1452:c07] track not nil
```

So the property track keeps its value and i can use it in other methods of the viewController class as well.

Has anybody experienced issues like this before, some explanation for this behaviour? or found a more elegant workaround than creating a dummy variable?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `track` property is specified as `weak` which makes it a zeroing weak reference. Presumably there are no other strong references to `track`. Adding the `track2` variable creates a strong reference to it, which makes it stick around. You probably don't want this property to be `weak`.